# Get Video from webcam / Ip-camera

Tags: c#, wpf, video-streaming, .net-4.5, video-capture

I'm trying to implement camera security in my application. I got some SDK's from some security companys  to implement there system but they all use ActiveX. My view right now is that ActiveX is kinda old?

But what is the newest way to get video from devices and display (stream) them on a screen?
What control to use in .net 4.5 WPF (and Windows 8)

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on video WPF app for two years now and we had a fundamental problem with video and WPF which was never resolved, and that's variable fps-rate. This blog [post](http://rhnatiuk.wordpress.com/2008/12/21/wpf-video-playback-problems/) goes into details.

There's also a nice library called [Media Kit](https://github.com/Sascha-L/WPF-MediaKit) (by Jeremiah Morrill), it might be suitable for your problem.

In our solution we had no choice but to expose HWND's for our rendering DirectX engine. We accomplished this by using [HwndHost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interop.hwndhost.aspx) class and extending it to our custom WPF control. Note this is the base class for windows forms host, so you get the same amount of problems as with WinForms-WPF inter op.

Also, ActiveX is the only way to display professional camera video streams in web interfaces, it's still a defacto industry standard, you'll get it from MOXA, Acti, Vivotek and various other camera equipment manufactureres.

One more thing, if you need to perform some advanced analysis of video, I'd suggest [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/).